# Users need to know the reason

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I hope user need to know the reason when one of their quwstions is/was deleted. This will also improve the site's quality as users will learn to ask quality questions from the reasons. Atleat the reason could be added as a comment before the question is deleted.

Comment: Do you have an example of a question being deleted without being put on hold first (which includes a reason) or without comments below it?

Comment: Users can see their own deleted questions and answers and so should be able to see the reasons why.

Comment: Yes,I have an example.    http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36712/accomodation-facilities-available-in-valparai

Answer (score 2):

The [sample question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36712/accomodation-facilities-available-in-valparai) you referred to was deleted by a mod, I am not a mod but I can guess why, here are few tips:

- The question seemed like spam, listing places and prices, not a good idea to advertise for places here. I am sure many readers flagged it as spam, even if it was not deleted by a mod, it would have been deleted automatically by the system.
- You asked a question and answered it yourself, in the same minute! Again not the best idea around here.
- Let's say it was not spam, a quick search in booking.com or any other hotels/hostels site would have revealed much better results, so what were you trying to do?

Comment: Check the link It will state what was i trying to do : http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/answering-my-own-question/1865#1865